# tkinter: fill = Y has no effect

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('My app')
root.minsize(250, 100)
label1 = Label(root, text = 'Hello world!', fg = 'red', bg = 'yellow',
               font = 'Monaco')
label1.pack(fill = X)
label2 = Label(root, text = 'Some more text!', fg = 'green', bg = 'cyan',
               font = 'Arial')
label2.pack(fill = Y)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run the code, `label1` stretches perfectly along the X axis while `label2` doesn't stretch at all along the Y axis. What am I missing?

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggODk.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is filling the space allocated for it. Tkinter will try to allocate the smallest amount of space necessary for the widget.

If you want tkinter to expand the widget to fill all remaining space, you need to set the `expand` attribute to `True`.

```
label2.pack(fill = Y, expand=True)
```

Comment: This, however, does not work with Button. Is there a deliberate layout difference between Buttons and Labels there?

Comment: @kakyo: are you using OSX? Buttons are a bit less configurable on that platform.

Comment: @kakyo Button inside frame? it can be a reason

Comment: @BryanOakley can you expand on your comment, and perhaps provide a link to more info?